# How to push the footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have seen many answers but none seem to work for me...
My footer has come right next to the paragraphs. How can I get them to down of the page... Also how to make the whole page be seen at the same time without needing to scroll down?

Below is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #85dcb8;
}

header {
  background: coral;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: black 4px solid;
  float: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

header p {
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.links {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to my web page</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, ab!
    </p>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 1</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 2</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 3</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 4 </a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 5</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 6</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    This webpage officialy belongs to Anirudh. Copyrights since 2020 &copy;
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Adding a margin and giving it a particular value makes it hard in math...So I would prefer some easier method with simple CSS.

[Image of how it looks for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW8yw.png)

Also any mistakes in my code that can be improved to make it more efficient?
Thanks.

EDIT: Adding an empty div helped me...Empty div with the class of clr and using clear:both; for the clr class in CSS works..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It seems to me as if it is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Let me add a pic to it.. Sorry

Comment: You're using float in your design, which makes the elements loose their height. Never ever use float in a design. Use display: flex or display: grid instead.

Comment: Thanks @RickardElimää... Will follow it from now on.

Comment: Yeah.. Got that... I removed the` float: center;` from the header..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #85dcb8;
}

header {
  background: coral;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: black 4px solid;
  float: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

header p {
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.links {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to my web page</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, ab!
    </p>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 1</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 2</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 3</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 4 </a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 5</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 6</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    This webpage officialy belongs to Anirudh. Copyrights since 2020 &copy;
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

It's working...

Comment: I copied last three paragraph and paste it ... and it's working..

Comment: It's working also in your changes..

Comment: But it is not working in my laptop

Comment: can you zoom out your browser...??

Comment: Yes I can zoom out.

Comment: it's working or not?? you need to copy all the correct code from here...

Comment: Have you made any changes in html file?

Comment: I have told you already...
footer{clear: both;}

Comment: If I add that to my code, it does not work.... But your code works fine.. So I though you have made some other changes as well

Comment: May be somewhere your code is not working....like some tag issues

Comment: @IshitaRay welcome to SO, I see you're contributing by helping the developers which is good and not to be picky here, you should not post multiple answers for the same post, you can post multiple answers in the same post, I just see there are 3 answers for the question, which is not correct. May be you're not aware of this but hope this helps. Continuing to do so you will have your answers down voted even though if that is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #85dcb8;
}

header {
  background: coral;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: black 4px solid;
  float: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

header p {
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.links {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to my web page</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, ab!
    </p>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 1</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 2</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 3</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 4 </a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 5</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 6</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    This webpage officialy belongs to Anirudh. Copyrights since 2020 &copy;
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

You can check now... it's working

Comment: What were the changes??

Comment: This works.... Can you please explain the changes.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```css
section, aside {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px); 
    /* here, replace 100px with the size of your header and footer */
}
```

This makes it so the main content is, at a minimum, the size of the screen minus the header and the footer size, thus pushing the footer to the bottom of the page.

As for the rest of your code, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you explain that line.... I don't know what is calc.

Comment: calc() basically means 100vh take away 100px, like a mathematical calculation

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh 100vh also means the height of the browser window. Also, did you find this answer helpful? If so, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: It helped me a bit... But did not get me to the solution

Comment: What are you getting? Is there another issue? I'll improve my post if you like, I just need the details

Comment: I did not understand what you have meant by height of the header and footer in the code's comment.... Also it requires a trial and error method to find the exact position for it.

Comment: yes, that is true - the height of the header and footer can be hard to find. but you can usually take a good guess and go from there, it shouldn't take too long

Comment: This makes a gap on the top of the page between the header and the paragraphs

Answer (score -2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #85dcb8;
}

header {
  background: coral;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: black 4px solid;
  float: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

header p {
  border-bottom: solid 5px black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.links {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to my web page</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, ab!
    </p>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 1</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 2</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 3</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 4 </a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 5</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 6</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 7</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 8</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 9</a></div>
      <div class="links"><a href="#">Page 10</a></div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 5</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Heading 6</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum facilis possimus consequuntur optio libero. Beatae praesentium officia quos odio saepe.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    This webpage officialy belongs to Anirudh. Copyrights since 2020 &copy;
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While they might solve the problem, answers without any explanation of changes made are not welcomed on SO. Feel free to add the explanation or at least mark the code you have altered.

Comment: Yeah... As mentioned by @ikiK, can you explain the changes in the code?

Comment: I just mentioned footer{clear: both}.

Comment: That did not help

Comment: Can you zoom out your screen and give me a screenshot??

Comment: I don't think I can use images in comments